# Windows 7 taskbar state with minimal code

Tags: c++, windows-7, console-application, taskbar

What would be the shortest code to set the state of a Windows 7 taskbar button for a known window handle?

The goal is to write a console utility that changes the progress and state (colour) of the console window taskbar item from a batch script. While the script performs different tasks, the taskbar item of its console window should represent the current state.

I get the window handle with the GetConsoleWindow() function, but then it seems to require loads of COM and Shell API stuff that I don't understand. One example I've found uses a whole GUI application with MFC to demonstrate the API, but most of it is way too complicated for my little tool and I don't understand it well enough to remove the stuff I don't need.

The tool should compile on Windows 7 with VS2010 (C++) but also run on earlier Windows versions (doing nothing if a feature is not available).

Comment: What do you mean by "taskbar state"? Do you mean just displaying progress or something else?

Comment: Yes, just progress and state (indeterminate, paused, error, i.e. the colours green, yellow and red). No jumplists, thumbnails or action buttons.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I created a class to set the progress in the Win7 taskbar for a project at one time. It's a wrapper for the [`ITaskBarList3`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface available from the Windows Shell. It's specifically done with [`ITaskBarList3.SetProgressState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391697%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`ITaskBarList3.SetProgressValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391698%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions.

This is the code I dug up:

```
#include <shobjidl.h>
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Shell32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Ole32.lib")

class Win7TaskbarProgress  
{
public:
    Win7TaskbarProgress();
    virtual ~Win7TaskbarProgress();

    void SetProgressState(HWND hwnd, TBPFLAG flag);
    void SetProgressValue(HWND hwnd, ULONGLONG ullCompleted, ULONGLONG ullTotal);

private:
    bool Init();
    ITaskbarList3* m_pITaskBarList3;
    bool m_bFailed;
};

Win7TaskbarProgress::Win7TaskbarProgress()
{
    m_pITaskBarList3 = NULL;
    m_bFailed = false;
}

Win7TaskbarProgress::~Win7TaskbarProgress()
{
    if (m_pITaskBarList3)   
    {
        m_pITaskBarList3->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
    }
}

void Win7TaskbarProgress::SetProgressState( HWND hwnd, TBPFLAG flag )
{
    if (Init())
        m_pITaskBarList3->SetProgressState(hwnd, flag);
}

void Win7TaskbarProgress::SetProgressValue( HWND hwnd, ULONGLONG ullCompleted, ULONGLONG ullTotal )
{
    if (Init())
        m_pITaskBarList3->SetProgressValue(hwnd, ullCompleted, ullTotal);
}

bool Win7TaskbarProgress::Init()
{
    if (m_pITaskBarList3)
        return true;

    if (m_bFailed)
        return false;
    
    // Initialize COM for this thread...
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskbarList, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ITaskbarList3, (void **)&m_pITaskBarList3);

    if (m_pITaskBarList3)
        return true;

    m_bFailed = true;
    CoUninitialize();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think I need this: `#include <ShObjIdl.h>` But what does `VERIFY()` do?

Comment: Nothing important, I removed edited my answer and removed it. It's like an ASSERT() but the statement still gets executed in Release builds. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcatwy09(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I've made a handy little tool out of this, extending my previous Flash-only feature. You can find it here: http://dev.unclassified.de/apps/flashconsolewindow

Comment: It does not work in multi-threaded application. If the method SetProgressState is called from a worker thread, then it crashes in Release().

Answer (score 0):

Note you still need to call `RegisterWindowMessage("TaskbarButtonCreated")` and `ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx()` to setup an message filter before `SetProgressValue()` can work.

According to the MSDN docs you are supposed to recreate your object each time you get the created message but I found I just had to do the `ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx()` and it works fine for normal circumstances.

Comment: I have written an application that uses `SetProgressValue` and works perfectly without `RegisterWindowMessage` nor `ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx`. As always, a lot of informations are missing in the documentation.