# Loading bar on Windows 7 or later

Tags: visual-c++

I think everyone saw loading bar in Windows, in Windows vista, 7 and 8 there us something interesting in this, you can see green loading on icon on taskbar. How create loading that work with this? I am newbie, I created text window where program is printing spaces with green background, this looks similar to loading bar. 
I don't know how create better loading...

Comment: Have you googled how to do this?  There are myriad examples on the web

Answer (score 1):

This is done with the [`ITaskBarList3`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface available from the Windows Shell. It's specifically done with [`ITaskBarList3.SetProgressState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391697%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`ITaskBarList3.SetProgressValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391698%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions.

There's a quick wrapper class here in [Windows 7 taskbar state in minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15002979/62576) that may help.

Comment: That might be a bit like handing out crack cocaine candy in a school yard.  When he says "text window printing spaces", he probably means "console window".

Comment: @Hans: He said "you can see green loading on icon on taskbar." and "create loading that work with this?". :-) You're probably right, though; that's why I found the minimal code example that does all the work. I have a great class for doing stuff with the TaskBarList interfaces, but it's all Delphi code.